# Running a react app built with Webpack 2 and code splitting. Not working when I just have static files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

So I've built a lovely react app. It's using Webpack 2 and code splitting, now I've built it and I have an index.html and a bunch of JS apps (bundle.js , 1.bundle.js and so on) in a build folder. I expected to just be able to statically serve these assets on a server that doesn't require node. (This is a requirement).

Have I got this wrong ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should have a problem serving static files. The way webpack builds the bundles innately runs the logic for loading your other bundles. I have been using Webpack 2 for this exact same thing, serving static files, and while not a React App, it works very well and should work the same here unless there's some important fact you've omitted. Perhaps you could share the error that is occuring?

Comment: It loads the bundle.js file in just fine, then the dynamic bundles (1.bundle.js) returns a 404. However its served up no different than the bundle.js file. The only difference is that there is no mention of them in the index.html file

Comment: does your main `bundle.js` have something similar to this in it?— `s.src=__webpack_require__.p+""+e+".min.js";` all of my build files are suffixed with `.min.js`, but you should at least have something similar in order for webpack to load the named bundles. the only thing i can think is if your file naming or paths are off somehow?